# how can i do a rounded toolbar/actionbar in android studio with code like this in the image?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, material-components, material-components-android

I'm trying to do this, with code and not with background image

[image: here you can find the example image i'm referring in the question]

Answer (score 2):

Define xml file like this 
(this is how i rounded my botton) 
put the xml file in drawable folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
>
<corners
    android:radius="25dip" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

and put the xml file in the background attribute

```
  <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dateButton"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"

            ></Button>
```

So maybe the same it works with toolbar ?

Comment: Did you notice that the OP states "with code and not with background image"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MaterialToolbar` in the Material Components Library:

In the layout use something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
    .../>
```

Then apply a [`MaterialShapeDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/MaterialShapeDrawable)

```
float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen....);
MaterialShapeDrawable toolbarBackground = (MaterialShapeDrawable) toolbar.getBackground();
toolbarBackground.setShapeAppearanceModel(
    toolbarBackground.getShapeAppearanceModel()
      .toBuilder()
      .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
      .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
      .build()
);
```

[image]

Comment: I can't use "setShapeAppearanceModel" because with the API that i'm using I can use "setShapedViewModel". how I can do it?

Comment: @feliznavidad Use the version 1.1.0-beta02.

Comment: of android studio? (posso parlare italiano) in quanto mi sa che siamo italiani entrambi

Comment: The version of the Material Component Library