# Is there any way to have a Toolbar with rounded corners inside a app bar layout?

Tags: android

I tried having a separate background file in the drawable folder but the only problem is that even though the toolbar's background has rounded corners underneath it seems that because of the app bar layout the toolbar has rounded corners under a square background .
this is the example of what I meant :[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmDNH.png)

This is my code of layout file:

```
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/searchbg">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/logo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/g_bold"
                    android:text="APP"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Kindly answer to my question :D

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59221483/how-can-i-do-a-rounded-toolbar-actionbar-in-android-studio-with-code-like-this-i/59224428#59224428)